# Codename One - setting a font in Javascript and HTML from local file

Tags: javascript, html, css, codenameone, font-face

I am creating a cross-platform app with Codename One, for iOS.

There's a BrowserComponent with a small HTML content and it has to feature a special font, I have the ttf file.

I am focused on iOS porting now, so I need instructions for using the font on the iOS install.

I need that the font is loaded from Javascript by this kind of instruction:

```
font = new FontFace('Material Icons','url(path)');
```

or also in CSS like:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Material Icons';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
src: url(path) format('ttf');
}
```

The important thing is the path for iOS install, and that it works in the webview at runtime.

Also alternate ways to achieve my goal can be done if you know about (Java or Javascript).

How to do that in Codename One?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest packaging your whole HTML directory in the html package in Codename One and use the browser hierarchy open API. This way HTML works as a single local directory and all relative paths within the HTML are resolved seamlessly since they resolve to local device paths. That font must then reside within the html directory (as well as the src directory if you use it in your app).

See the [setURLHierarchy](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/BrowserComponent.html#setURLHierarchy-java.lang.String-) API.

Comment: There's no html folder in src directory, and it does not let me create a new folder there. What I have to do?

Comment: You can create a package which is the same thing

Comment: I created the html folder under src directory, and put the html file inside the html folder. In code I put this instruction: webView.setURLHierarchy("/fileName.html"); but I get the "File not found" error. What's wrong?

Comment: This should work, see this test case: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/9a7df45fd84200f9456d0de116ff44ed90708c9d/Samples/samples/SetPageURLHierarchyTest/SetPageURLHierarchyTest.java

Comment: It's strange, even your sample code does not work, file is not found. The html folder is under src. Note that if I do a refactor to rename the html folder, it finds two occurrences of it (but pointing to the same folder).

Comment: How are you running this? The html package is a special case where the contents get zipped and explicitly extracted to a special file system location. The files shouldn't be accessible in any other way except for the setURLHierarchy API

Comment: I do not understand this package, I created a package like a folder, and I expect to access the html file inside. What do you mean?

Comment: How do you access the HTML file inside? The only way is through the specific hierarchy API and treating the HTML directory as if it's root to a relative HTML hierarchy.

Comment: I followed the documentation: webView.setURLHierarchy("/filename.html");

Comment: Can you post a test project on github?

Comment: You have posted one already. It does not work too as I said. Maybe now you can suggest some debug test on your sample project itself.

Comment: It works for us, did you test it using our sample tool or by copying it into a project?
What I want to see isn't the code, I want to see how you structured the whole project to see if there's a nuance at that stage that we missed.

Comment: Continued on Codename Google Groups discussion